# How to add CSS Transition for button sliding

Tags: angularjs, css

I am new to css transitions and i want to add sliding effect for my buttons "option1" and "option2" when i click on "view more". These buttons should appear from behind view more.

I am currently using `ng-if` to hide and show two of my buttons

```
<div class="bottom-right">
<button class="btn button1" ng-click="showAll()">view more</button>
<button ng-if="viewmore"  class="btn button1">option1</button>
<button ng-if="viewmore"  class="btn button1">option2</button>
</div>
```

how can i do that?

here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HA7RzM3FPXlEb5g7Jh4r?p=preview

Comment: Are you constrained to this specific version of angular?

Comment: yes i am constrained to this specific version of angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd recommend using ngAnimate to achieve that effect.

Since angular 1.2.* came out approximately 2 years ago, 
here's a great article that explains how to achieve exactly what you need with this version:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-nginclude-ngview-and-ngif

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a really good example from the [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) documentation.

```
<div ng-init="checked=true">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"> Is Visible...
  </label>
  <div class="check-element sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked" style="clear:both;">
    Visible...
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.sample-show-hide {
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
 background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
 -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
 transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
 opacity:0;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: The documentation is for 1.4, wouldn't do so well for 1.2.*